# Java: Estoy intentando hacer un algoritmo recursivo que me muestre los datos de un archivo txt buscando solo la id de la persona

Tags: java, recursión, txt, interface, filereader

> La primera linea del archivo si me la lee correctamente pero las demás ya no las muestra en mi interface de usuario, al parecer mi algoritmo recursivo no retorna la clase para leer las líneas siguientes.

```
private Boolean btnBuscarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_btnBuscarActionPerformed
    String limite = " "; // Elemento que separa el nombre, el usuario y la contraseña dentro del fichero
    String[] trozos; // Dividimos la linea del dichero en unidades independientes
    String ID; // Nombre del sitio que el usuario ha introducido en el cuadro de texto
    String IDTrozo; // Nombre del sitio dentro del string trozos
    Boolean encontrado = false; // Para saber si hemos encontrado el sitio que buscabamos
    jTextNombre.setText("");
    jTextEdad.setText("");
    jTextSexo.setText("");
    jTextDireccion.setText("");
    jTextPuesto.setText("");
    if (jTextID.getText().equals("")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "El campo del ID está vacío", "Campo vacío", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            return false;}
```

> > En esta parte declare mi botón y las variables que usare para separar las líneas.

```
else {
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fichero));  // Cargamos el fichero
            String linea = reader.readLine(); // leemos la primera linea
            if (linea == null) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "El fichero está vacío", "Fichero vacío", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                return false;
            } else {
                    trozos = linea.split(limite,6); //Dividimos la linea leida en tres parte
                    ID = jTextID.getText().toUpperCase();
                    IDTrozo = trozos[0].toUpperCase();
                if (IDTrozo.equals(ID)) {
                     encontrado = true;// si la id es igual muestra los pedazos divididos en los cuadros de texto
                    jTextNombre.setText(trozos[1]);
                    jTextEdad.setText(trozos[2]);
                    jTextSexo.setText(trozos[3]); 
                    jTextDireccion.setText(trozos[4]);
                    jTextPuesto.setText(trozos[5]);
                    String Liberador = trozos [6]; 
                    linea = reader.readLine();// lee la siguiente línea
                    return (linea != null);
                    }
                     
                if (!encontrado) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "No se han encontrado coincidencias", "No hay coincidencias", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    return false; 
                }
            } //reader.close();// Cerramos el fichero   
        } 
        catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MenuConsultar.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }return btnBuscarActionPerformed(evt);
}
```

> Y en esta parte lee el fichero, despues lee la primera liea verificando si el archivo tiene algo. Si el archivo tiene algo procede a dividirlo en 6 pedazos, lee lo que el usuario escribió en el cuadro de texto y procede a compararlo con el trozo 0 que es el de la id. Si es igual me muestra la linea en trozos para cada cuadro y si no lo es me manda un cuadro de texto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Pero ya no lee despúes de la linea 1 y me manda al cuadro de texto.

Comment: Por que lo quieres recursivo, usualmente es iterativo => vas a recorrer todas las líneas del archivo buscando el id. Por otro lado, no es una respuesta , pero debes aclararte que tu algoritmo no es recursivo de ningun modo, ya que cuando encuentra una segunda línea NO NULA, devuelve true, y  y eso es todo. Nunca llegará al return final.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisa primero mi comentario, te ofrezco esta solución no recursiva, tomando en cuenta que casi nunca se aplica un algoritmo recursivo a la lectura de un archivo (ya que es secuencial y gasta demasiados recursos).

Dicho eso, la segunda parte de tu código debería cambiarse por esto:

```
else {
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fichero));  // Cargamos el fichero
            String linea = reader.readLine(); // leemos la primera linea

            if (linea == null) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "El fichero está vacío", "Fichero vacío", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                return false;
            }

            ID = jTextID.getText().toUpperCase(); //No es necesario leerlo cada iteración del bucle, una sola vez basta

            while(linea!=null) {
                trozos = linea.split(limite,6); //Dividimos la linea leida en tres parte
                
                IDTrozo = trozos[0].toUpperCase();
                if (IDTrozo.equals(ID)) {
                    encontrado = true;// si la id es igual muestra los pedazos divididos en los cuadros de texto
                    jTextNombre.setText(trozos[1]);
                    jTextEdad.setText(trozos[2]);
                    jTextSexo.setText(trozos[3]); 
                    jTextDireccion.setText(trozos[4]);
                    jTextPuesto.setText(trozos[5]);
                    String Liberador = trozos [6]; 
                    return(encontrado);  //no terminará el bucle, este return se anticipa y termina inmediatamente la llamada de la función
                }
                //si no es el id buscado,....
                linea = reader.readLine();// lee la siguiente línea
            }

            //Si llega a terminar el bucle anterior, es por que no hay más líneas y encontrado == falso
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "No se han encontrado coincidencias", "No hay coincidencias", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            return encontrado;  //que en este punto es falso

        } 
        catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MenuConsultar.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    return false; //solo si capturó algún error en el try catch
}
```

Comment: Entiendo, entonces estaba haciendo desperdicio de recursos y no llegaría a mi return final. Te agradezco que me hayas aclarado los errores que tengo para mejorarlos :D